# How to read a JSON object asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I run 20 functions at once asynchronously reading an object in my browser on the same page?

```
var myLargeOBJECT = {}; // object on page



var  read1 = function(){
   $.getJSON( myLargeOBJECT, function( json ) {
      console.dir( json);
    });

}

// etc
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want asynchronous, or synchronous. And why can't you do what you've posted already? what do you want to change about it? what's wrong with it? all you are doing is declaring variables and storing a function in them.

Comment: Why would you read one and the same (?) data multiple times anyway? Load it once, asynchronously – and then call all your functions in the callback, passing the data to them.

Comment: Not sure if I should +1 or -1 for the most creative misspelling of asynchronous I've seen today

Comment: are all the 20 functions contain ajax requests to get the json object?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to run the functions synchronously, but the ajax asynchronously? still confused. Accessing an object has nothing to do with asynchronous vs synchronous.

Comment: yes----------------------------------

Comment: So, you want the ajax calls to update the object, then be able to access the object fully modified without a callback, without making the ajax synchronous? **not possible**.

Comment: i think the OP wants ajax requests running independently for each and every function call....

Comment: I think there is one data oject which is the datasource for 20 functions e.g. Fuction1(myLargeOBJECT);Function2(myLargeOBJECT); where then the problem is that Function2 will only fire once Function1 has completed

Comment: Why would the object being a source of data cause function 2 to only fire after function 1 is completed?

Comment: function1 and function2 are synchronous objects, function 1 e.g. does not perhaps contain a ajax call. Thats my thinking anyway, I'm interested as I'm also battling with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try threads in java script there are some libs in the web i haven't used them but i think that it's what you need, i check and there is one easy and good for what you are doing
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsthread/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function function1(){
   //Do something
  }

function function2(){
 //Do something
}
    
    Concurrent.Thread.create(function1);
    Concurrent.Thread.create(function2);    
</script>
```

Comment: e.g. Concurrent.Thread.create(function1());
    Concurrent.Thread.create(function2());?

Answer (score 1):

use $.ajax instead and set async = true or async = false as per your requirement

```
$.ajax({
 url: myUrl,
 dataType: 'json',
 async: true,
 data: myData,
 success: function(data) {
//stuff
  }
});
```